# How to solve errors due to adding method class using decorators?

Tags: python, class, decorator

I'm trying to add a method class using decorator, but I get errors after tests
FIRST WAY:

```
from functools import wraps
    def add_class_method(name_class):
        def real_decorator(items):
            @wraps(items)
            def class_method(self,*args, **kwargs):
                    return items(*args, **kwargs)
            setattr(name_class, items.__name__, classmethod(class_method))
            return class_method
        return real_decorator
```

Error:

> class_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

SECOND WAY:

```
def add_class_method(name_class):
    def real_decorator(items):
        @classmethod
        @wraps(items)
        def class_method(self,*args, **kwargs):
                return items(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(name_class, items.__name__, class_method)
        return class_method
    return real_decorator
```

ERROR:

> 'classmethod' object is not callable

```
class A:
pass

@add_class_method(A)
def foo():
    return "Hello!"

assert A.foo() == "Hello!"
```

Which way is better and what should I change/add?

Comment: ```def add_class_method(self, name_class):```

Comment: It doesn't work :(